# How to understand "SomeInts Int Ints"?

Tags: haskell

This is my code on Haskell.

```
module CustomLists where

-- | A list of Int elements
data Ints = NoInts | SomeInts Int Ints
  deriving Show

-- Examples:
ints :: Ints
ints = SomeInts 1 (SomeInts 2 (SomeInts 3 NoInts))

-- | noInts
-- Examples:
-- >>> noInts NoInts
-- True
-- >>> noInts ints
-- False
noInts :: Ints -> Bool
noInts x = case x of
 NoInts -> True
 otherwise -> False
```

Should I use 'otherwise' here? Is there a better or more specific way to write the function?

Comment: You should definitely adjust this post so that the grammar was correct and the code was *in the post* and formatted nicely. I will then gladly help you solve your predicaments.

Comment: Complete what function? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Hello, I'd recommend checking out the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask questions. Also, take a look at some of the other questions asked here to get a rough idea on what format your questions should be in, then try asking again.

Comment: Your question looks much better after your edit. I've fixed a few things in it and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a good style question with respect to when to use an explicit constructor, `otherwise`, or perhaps `_`.  Let's say we have your data type:

```
data Ints = NoInts | SomeInts Int Ints
```

And you'd like to perform some operation.  Which operation you are performing will dictate what solution you should probably use.  For example, if you are just making a boolean check to see if the constructor is `NoInts` or not then a wild card is wise:

```
noInts :: Ints -> Bool
noInts x =
  case x of
    NoInts -> True
    _      -> False
```

Notice we use `_` instead of `otherwise` because `otherwise` is just a variable name. If you turned on warnings the there are two you'd likely see 1. Shadowed definition of `otherwise` since in your pattern `otherwise = x` but in the Prelude `otherwise = True`.  2. Unused variable `otherwise` since the expression `False` doesn't use it.

All this said, there are other cases where it is better to explicitly match on the constructor.  Let's say you were performing some computation:

```
someComputation :: Ints -> Int
someComputation x =
  case x of
    SomeInts x xs -> x + someComputation xs
    NoInts   -> 0
```

Now if you expand the definition of `Ints` to include another constructor, say `| PerhapsInts [Int]` you'll get a warning at `someComputation` - thus the compiler will tell you where in your code this new constructor should be considered.  If you had used `_ -> 0` for the second case then the compiler wouldn't give such a warning and it is hard to leverage the compiler when adding features or refactoring.